# Airflow share cookies between SimpleHttpOperator

Tags: python, cookies, airflow

```
login_task = SimpleHttpOperator()
mutation_task = SimpleHttpOperator()
```

The `login_task` sets the cookie. How could this cookie be shared with the `mutation_task`?

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue. Problem is that `HttpHook.run()` called by the operator re-instantiates a new `Session()` each time the operator is called.

I was about to write a custom hook/operator but found out that `SimpleHttpOperator` passes on `**kwargs` to `prepare.Request()` in `run()`.

Since the operator returns the `response` object, the solution is simple:

```
# save only the cookies returned to XCom
login_task= SimpleHttpOperator(
    ...,
    response_filter=lambda response: response.cookies
)

# run multiple related tasks but before the cookie expires
mutation_task = SimpleHttpOperator(
    ...,
    cookies={{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="login_task") }}
)
```

That works for me for now but this is far from ideal as you may need to refresh the cookie quite often, hence more tasks. Also, if you use the `KubernetesExecutor`, it is ridiculous to start a `Pod` just for getting a cookie...

For reference, the source code for the operator and hook:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-http/stable/_api/airflow/providers/http/index.html